# Linux Distro with g++

Tags: linux, ubuntu, g++

I am having a bit of a nightmare running up an Ubuntu distribution on an offline machine. Can anyone advise a distribution of Linux with G++ (or the contents of the build essential ubuntu package) as standard?

It is an absolute nightmare trying to download all the dependencies separately and I'm not getting on with Keryx at all. Many people have noted that build-essential package is available on the Ubuntu install CD but I can't find it on the 12.04 install CD using

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I could do with a distribution with g++ in the basic install so I can get on with my day!

Comment: Have you tried `apt-cache search g++`? Show us the output if `g++ --version` after installing `build-essential`?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the machine to the network?

Comment: Order or dowload a set of Debian DVDs.  That will include all the main packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A source distribution like Gentoo will provides all tools needed for compiling like g++